# How to optimise the program to solve RecursionError: maximum recursion

Tags: python

The aim of this program is to find all the integer pairs of three that are in range of 0 and 57 that can form a triangle. (I made the program for a Math problem)

```
import random
import time
dict = {}
current_list = []
key_num = 0
def main():
    global key_num
    a = random.randint(1, 57)
    b = random.randint(1, 57)
    c = random.randint(1, 57)
    if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
        current_list.append(a)
        current_list.append(b)
        current_list.append(c)
        current_list.sort()
        for i in range(0, key_num):
            if dict[i] == current_list:
                main()
        dict.setdefault(key_num, current_list) 
        key_num += 1
        current_list.clear()
        print(str(key_num))
        print(dict)
        time.sleep(0.8)     
while True:
    main()
```

However, when I run it, there are two problems.

First, after a while program is launched, an error *RecursionError: maximum recursion* is displayed. For this, I have tried to set the limit higher to 10^5 but the program just crashed after a while.

Second, the dictionary isn't inputting any new items during the process.

I am not that experienced in python and thanks a lot if you would like to help.

*Also, a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a is the criteria for an triangle: the sum of any two sides is bigger than the third side.*

Comment: In your own words, when you call `main()` from within `main()`, what *exactly* do you expect to happen as a result?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by `if dict[i] == current_list: main()`?

Comment: Why are you recursing at all? At what point do you expect the recursion to stop?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name. That's a builtin function.

Comment: In your own words, why is `dict` a dictionary? What do you expect the keys to look like? Also, what problem do you hope to solve by searching through that dictionary? In your own words, what is the *purpose of* a dictionary?

Comment: Okay guys, let's be real. OP is clearly quite new. Berating him about a dictionary not being useful isn't going to be helpful. I would put money on him not knowing himself why he's using a dictionary. We just need to explain to him what tools he should be using instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so first of all, in general stack overflow questions should be condensed to the point that their answers can be useful to others.

Now, there are several problem with your code:

1. you call main inside main. When you say:

```
if dict[i] == current_list:
    main()
```

what I think you mean is: if this set of integers has already been checked, go back to the beginning. But instead it runs the function main() again, this time inside of itself. What you should do instead is write:

```
if dict[i] == current_list:
    return
```

2. You don't have an end condition. The code won't stop because there is no way for it to exit the loop. You need some way to determine when it is finished.
3. `dict.setdefault(key_num, current_list)` has several issues. Number one is that the way you assign an item to a dictionary is: `dict[key_num] = current_list`. `setdefault` is a totally different thing and, while it somtimes produces the same result, it isn't the thing you are looking for.
4. The next issue is that you clear current_list in the next line, which means the list that you just put into your dictionary is now an empty list.

My recommendation is to restructure the code into several for loops to check every combination:

```
identifiedSets = [];
for a in range(1, 57):
    for b in range(1, 57):
        for c in range(1, 57):
            if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
                newList = [a, b, c]
                newList.sort();
                identifiedSets.append(str(newList))

print(str(identifiedSets))
```

This way you will iterate through every possible combination of numbers and, by storing the results as a list of strings, you can check if those strings have already been added to the list. Finally, printing the results is easy because the results are already strings.

Comment: Thank you so much for bothering to help me. You see, I am a starter and I have to scratch down information from google from a lot of websites. This caused my program to be messy and doesn't make any sense. Thank you so much again to help me.

Comment: @StarterPeter No problem. If you need more help my discord handle is here: https://1ty.me/Ay74Q